# Saving output after choosing option menu (python - Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm attempting to save the choice of the user [Red, Green-red, Green-blue, blue] after the user hits the okay button and the window closes in Tkinter... I've put this together so far using things I've found online but I can't deduce a "simple" way of doing this?

```
def select_channel():
     OPTIONS = [
       "Red",
       "Green-red",
       "Green-blue",
       "Blue"
    ]

    master = tk.Tk()

    var = tk.StringVar(master)
    var.set(OPTIONS)  # initial value

    option = tk.OptionMenu(master, var, *OPTIONS)
    option.pack()


    def ok():
       print("value is", var.get())
       channel = var.get()
       master.destroy()

    button = tk.Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
    button.pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Any thoughts? I save it under channel but its not available outside of that function. hmm

Comment: `save` usually means save in file but you only `assign to variable` - if you want to save it in file then do it inside function `ok()`. OR use `global channel` inside function `ok()` to assign to global variable and it will be availabel outside function.

Comment: You want to save the state of the app, so it can be restored for the next session, or you need to keep track of the choices for further use?

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` to assign value to global variable

```
def ok():
    global channel

    print("value is", var.get())
    channel = var.get()
    master.destroy()
```

---

**BTW:** There is no sense to use `return channel` because function is executed by button and it can't returned value and assign to other value.

---

**BTW:** If you want save only `channel` then maybe do it inside function `ok()`

---

**BTW:** You should use `[0]` in `var.set(OPTIONS[0])` to set only first element as default/initial value.

---

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def select_channel():

     def ok():
         global channel

         #print("value is", var.get())
         channel = var.get()
         master.destroy()

     OPTIONS = [
       "Red",
       "Green-red",
       "Green-blue",
       "Blue"
     ]

     master = tk.Tk()

     var = tk.StringVar(master)
     var.set(OPTIONS[0])  # initial value

     option = tk.OptionMenu(master, var, *OPTIONS)
     option.pack()

     button = tk.Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
     button.pack()

     tk.mainloop()

# --- main ---

select_channel()
print('after closing window:', channel)
```

Comment: `channel` is not defined anywhere in the posted code except where it is assigned inside `ok()`

Comment: @AlanHoover it doesn't matter it will create global variable when you assing value. But if this i problem then create it at start with some default value (outside functions to create global variable). OP wants to get value from `channel` after leaving function `ok()` and probably use it in code which OP doesn't show.